# На каком языке пишутся плагины для веб-браузеров?

Tags: плагин, браузер

-

Comment: на javascript

Comment: некоторые простые вещи делал для веб сайтов на js и почему то даже не подозревал что на нем пишутся плагины. Спасибо, обрадовали :)

Comment: Тогда это, обычно, называют не плагинами (plugin), а расширениями (extension) или аддонами (add-on).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если речь про т.н. плагины [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) или его производные — на любом. Условием является возможность создать динамически подгружаемую библиотеку (.dll/.so), реализующую и экспортирующую ряд функций с [определенным API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference).

На практике, чаще всего используют C, как наиболее привыкшийся разработчикам.

Если речь идет о т.н. расширениях ([1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension), [2](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)) — как правило, на JavaScript, или, как вариант, [компилируемые в него языки](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS).

Чаще всего, пожалуй, рациональнее писать расширение, нежели плагин. Плагин нужен, если требуется что-то довольно специфичное, например кодирование видео, или работа с устройствами компьютера.